# Clustering or factor analysis for dimensionality reduction in multivariate linear regression

Tags: regression, clustering, factor-analysis, high-dimensional, many-categories

I have dataset describing aggregated purchases from multiple brands. It contains variables:

- Brand (ordinal)
- Promotion (ordinal)
- Sales (numeric)

I need to use linear regression to describe the effect of different brands and promotions on the amount of Sales. The cardinality of Promotion is low, 2 unique values, but the cardinality of feature Brand is high, around 100. As far as I understand I cannot perform One-Hot-Encoding on Brands because I will get really sparse data and the regression would be hard to interpret.

So should I do factor analysis on Brands and try to maybe group them in a meaningful way?

My idea involves, grouping Brands according to their amount of Sales, or according to their purchase frequency (how many people buy from these brands).

The above dataset was created from the base dataset containing individual purchases. It contains variables:

- Brand (ordinal)
- Promotion (ordinal)
- Quantity
- Spent value
- Date
  It may be beneficial to my analysis, but I am not yet sure on it.

Can you help me on that?

Results of linear regression model without regularisation with one-hot-encoded variables Brand and Promo. Brand has over 118 unique values and dataset has around 192 datapoints. Thus the linear regression model seems to be overfitted. All the coefficients have p > 0.05 and do not seem to be significant.
[image]

Comment: "Should" is a fraught question.  There are lots of things you can do.  I would use a RF myself, but mileage varies, and I like my favorite tools, maybe more than you do.  
For date, use date-cosines, and do it over week, month, and quarter.  https://github.com/tidyverse/lubridate/issues/731

Comment: This task of describing sales with regard to the brand and promotion do not involve Date variable, but would help in factor analysis. The thing is that I don't know what would be the best approach in that task. 

What does abbreviation RF stand for? Random Forest tree methods?

Comment: Factor analysis applies to settings where a large number of numerical variables is explained by a weighted linear combination of a small number of numerical factors. I doubt your case qualifies as such. Check out the [tag:many-categories] tag. I have little experience with it, but perhaps one-hot encoding coupled with regularized estimation (ridge regression or a Bayesian approach) could work.

Comment: I engineered some new features: Frequency of purchases, and average price per each brand. So now I have dataset containing Brands, Promotion and Total Number of spent value on each brand, expanded with these two. 
How should I start tackle the problem of describing relations with linear regression between spent value on each brand and two independent variables like Brand and Promotion?
I wanted to cluster brands because of their high cardinality, using frequency and average price, but I don't see any visible clusters. I don't know how to deal with encoding brands with some factor.

Comment: My idea was quite simple – probably too simple: run a linear regression of Sales on Brand (one-hot encoded) and Promotion (a dummy) using regularized estimation (e.g. ridge or Bayesian). You could add the time dimension via the Date variable to make it a panel data model with time fixed effects or something like that, again using regularization.

Comment: My instinct here, given the description of your data and your research question, would be to use mixed effects modelling, treating 'brand' as a random effect and promotion as a fixed effect.  You could then add a random 'slope' for the effect of promotion varying by brand.  But it really depends on what exactly you want to know from this data.

Comment: I need to use linear regression to describe the effect of different brands and promotions on the amount of Sales. Thus, I believe I need to build a model with two inputs: Brand (categorical) and Promotion (categorical) and output as a Sales (Numeric).
What I did was clustered Brands (categorical) with Kmeans according to other available features somewhat related to Sales: Quantity and volume sold. Then with analysis: Elbow method and Silhouette analysis, I found optimal number of clusters equal to 3. Then I mapped these brands into 3 clusteres, and finally fed the linear regression model.

Comment: What do you think about this approach? @GeorgeSavva

Comment: @RichardHardy I have 192 data points. The variable Brand has 118 unique values and Promo variable has 2 unique values (Yes or no). Isn't that too little data points and LR wouldn't be overfitted?
If I one-hot-encode Brand and Promo and fit the linear regression I would get the model summary

Comment: Yes, I think there would be overfitting if you used unregularized estimation. That is why I explicitly suggested regularization or use of a Bayesian approach.

Comment: @RichardHardy I added the summary of the model to the main topic desc. Thank you for aid.

Comment: I think using three clusters makes a huge assumption that the effects you are interested in would be similar within the clusters.